# Can you set the details element to display grid?

Tags: css, css-grid, html-tag-details

I wanted to create a filter element that can be collapsed using the `<details>` element as it comes out of the box with an `open/close` functionality.

However when it came to styling the fields inside, I wanted to use grid and it seems like `<details>` can't be set to `display: grid`?

Has anyone come across this behavior?

Your input is much appreciated!

```css
details {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

label:first-of-type {
  color: red;
  grid-column: 1;
}

label:last-of-type {
  color: blue;
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <details open>
    <summary>Filter</summary>
    <label>
        I should be on the left
        <input type="text">
      </label>
    <label>
        I should be on the right
        <input type="text">
      </label>
  </details>
</form>
```

[Codepen here!](https://codepen.io/sammiepls/pen/OoxKZb)

Comment: Indeed, strange. Would it be an option to put the elements you'd like to grid-align in a container that is set to display: grid?

Comment: I think that's the route I'll have to go down. I have added a div inside the details and that seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have had to wrap the form `input`'s within the details in a `<div>` or another container to get `display: grid` to work and style them.